# Looping over all the parent attributes in addition to child attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have created an XSLT transformation to convert the below XML to CSV

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Package ID="1122" BusinessID="001233" Version="19.0.2" xsi:type="Doms">
    <Name>ABC</Name>
    <Description> Desc sample</Description>
    <Category>54</Category>
    <Business_ID>001233</Business_ID>

    <TPFC ID="76" xsi:type="TPFC" Pattern="Th_Branch">
        <Name>AM</Name>
        <Parent ID="11d" xsi:type="TPFC" Pattern="Th_Branch">
            <Description>Mob1</Description>
            <Name>Mob1</Name>
            <Parent ID="12F" xsi:type="TPFC" Pattern="Th_Branch">
            <Description>Mob2</Description>
            <Name>Mob2</Name>
            </Parent>
        </Parent>
    </TPFC>
</Package>
```

Below is the XSLT I have created to loop over the nodes

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>
    <!-- Delimiter -->
    <xsl:variable name="separator" select="'|'"/>
    <!-- New line character -->
    <xsl:variable name="newline" select="'&#10;'"/>
<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <!-- header -->
    <xsl:text>id|name|description|parent_name|parent_id|level|total_level|product_offering_id</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
    <!-- data -->
    <xsl:for-each select="Package">
        <xsl:variable name="b-id" select="Business_ID" />
        <!-- TPFC data -->
        <xsl:for-each select="TPFC ">
          <xsl:value-of select="translate(Name,' ',''), .//Parent/Name" separator="_"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$separator"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$separator"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="Description"/>
    
<xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
          <xsl:for-each select="//Parent">
            <xsl:value-of select="translate(Name,' ',''), .//Parent/Name" separator="_"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$separator"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$separator"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="Description"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
       </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The current outcome is A CSV with a record created for the parent and child node in TPFC.

```
 | id           | name | description | 
  | AM_Mob1_Mob2 | AM   |             | 
  | Mob1_Mob2    | Mob1 |             | 
  | Mob2         | Mob2 | Mob 2       |
```

Is there any other better way to iterate over all the nodes with same **xsi:type=TPFC** or is there a way to reuse the xsl select statements that are used repeatedly in the two for-each statement

Comment: Your posted XML sample has a single `Package` so a `for-each select="Package"` seems pointless. There not even a single `TProduct_Family_Classification` in the input sample so it is hard to understand what that second `for-each` is meant to achieve. The text asks about `better way to iterate over all the nodes with same xsi:type=TPFC` but I don't see any code to process nodes based on that attribute value. Based on that, I am not sure what you want to achieve and what kind of improvement you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, its not TProduct_Family_Classification , rather its TPFC - i have changed it in the code. 
better way to iterate over all the nodes with same xsi:type=TPFC - by this i meant if we can iterate over the elements that have the same xsi:type = TPFC, which in the above examples is - TPFC and Parent. Right now Im iterating over them separately , instead i would like to consider all the nodes. I have although sorted this issue by using call-template now.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, its not TProduct_Family_Classification , rather its TPFC - i have changed it in the code. by better way, i meant if we can iterate over the elements that have the same xsi:type = TPFC, which in the above examples is - TPFC and Parent. Right now Im iterating over them separately which still works and i have incorporated call-template now. So that i still use the same structure but reusing the xsl:select statements. If you think there is any better way to iterate using xsi:type irrespective of the element name, kindly let me know